# Overlay signals in the scope of Xcos (Scilab)

Tags: scilab, xcos

[image]

The above image is the result of using the `cmscope` block, but I want to overlap the signals. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should use a multiplexer, the `MUX` block, with the single display scope, `CSCOPE`. The image below shows what you should do.

[image]

The `MUX` put all the incoming signals (which are actually vectors of data) into a single matrix and pass it forward in the simulation. Whenever you need all your data in a single variable, use a `MUX`.

In this case, it sends a matrix with 2 columns to the plot function that lies within `CSCOPE`, whereas in your original problem, you pass two matrix of 1 column each to `CMSCOPE` which uses something like `subplot()` to create separated curves.